unable to resolve pom due to unknown repo
I stumbled onto openrewrite, thought it was interesting and useful. So, I did the necessary config by following what others have done. I tried to dryRun it, I get the following error during pom resolution:
[WARNING] Failed to access maven repository http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org
java.net.UnknownHostException: snapshots.repository.codehaus.org
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect (NioSocketImpl.java:567)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:751)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect (SSLSocketImpl.java:304)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect (NetworkClient.java:178)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer (HttpClient.java:531)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer (HttpClient.java:636)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init> (HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New (HttpsClient.java:377)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1237)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect (HttpURLConnection.java:1123)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream (HttpURLConnection.java:1599)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode (HttpURLConnection.java:531)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:307)
    at org.openrewrite.ipc.http.HttpUrlConnectionSender.send (HttpUrlConnectionSender.java:97)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.lambda$sendRequest$1 (MavenPomDownloader.java:146)
    at dev.failsafe.Functions.lambda$toCtxSupplier$11 (Functions.java:243)
    at dev.failsafe.Functions.lambda$get$0 (Functions.java:46)
    at dev.failsafe.internal.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$apply$0 (RetryPolicyExecutor.java:74)
    at dev.failsafe.SyncExecutionImpl.executeSync (SyncExecutionImpl.java:187)
    at dev.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.call (FailsafeExecutor.java:376)
    at dev.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.get (FailsafeExecutor.java:112)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.sendRequest (MavenPomDownloader.java:145)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.normalizeRepository (MavenPomDownloader.java:752)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.distinctNormalizedRepositories (MavenPomDownloader.java:674)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.download (MavenPomDownloader.java:511)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentPom (ResolvedPom.java:497)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentDependenciesRecursively (ResolvedPom.java:432)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentsRecursively (ResolvedPom.java:380)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:889)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:805)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.MavenResolutionResult.resolveDependencies (MavenResolutionResult.java:174)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenParser.parseInputs (MavenParser.java:116)
    at org.openrewrite.Parser.parse (Parser.java:59)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenMojoProjectParser.parseMaven (MavenMojoProjectParser.java:557)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenMojoProjectParser.listSourceFiles (MavenMojoProjectParser.java:149)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.loadSourceSet (AbstractRewriteMojo.java:258)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.listResults (AbstractRewriteMojo.java:240)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteDryRunMojo.execute (AbstractRewriteDryRunMojo.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)

I am not sure what it is looking up, I'm not using any nexus repo and I understand maven blocks http urls now. I tried with a mirrorOf as suggested in the official site:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots
still the same thing. I tried dryRunning/Running the recipes outside of IDE as well, no luck.
I tried running it on a dummy project, there it worked fine. I am not sure why it's not resolving pom of my work project. Below is my plugin setup:
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.29.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <activeRecipes>
                        <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.UpgradeSpringBoot_3_2</recipe>
                        <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.migrate.UpgradeToJava21</recipe>
                    </activeRecipes>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rewrite-java-dependencies</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rewrite-spring</artifactId>
                        <version>5.8.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>


A dry run does not create any code changes; you'll likely want to use mvn rewrite:run instead. The stacktrace you've given above is just a warning. We're working through this issue to get that sorted.

I tried with run. But the pom resolution is breaking and recipe is not applied to the pom as mentioned in the GitHub issue. I see a bom release there, will try that out.

Perhaps you could reduce our pom.xml down to a minimal sample and share that in the issue? I've not been able to reproduce any failed recipe runs so far.

To be clear, only in the pom file the recipe is not applied. the java upgrade changes are created in .patch file and are being applied as well. attached pom.xml

Ah that's helpful context, thanks! I thought nothing was applied initially. A reproducer project would help narrow this down if you're able to create that and put it on GitHub.

didn't need much fuss, just a starter project with the same pom reproduced the issue for me. https://github.com/manidkandan/trial
